# D3 enter() and draw different component each loop

Tags: typescript, d3.js

I want to write table with tr and td, my problem is how to write column with condition,

```
let d3data: any[][] = this.defaultData();
```

and this is sample the row data

```
let d3data[0]=[1, "Malang", 2017, [{date:1, value:200},{date:2, value:100},{date:3, value:500}]];
```

that is sample row with column 4 is array data and i need to create line chart with that data, I'm already has function to create line chart but how to use the html()?

```
tr.selectAll("div")
        .data(function (d, i) {
            return d;
        })
        .enter().append("div")
        .attr('class', function (d, i) {
            return "" + KpiMatrix.COLUMNS[i];
        })
        .html(function (d, i) {
            if (Array.isArray(d)) {
                return that.createLineChart(d, this);
            }
            return d;
        });
```

is there any function to draw/render multi element? 
I use html and define if the data is array then call createLineChart but column chart never render.

this is my function to create chart

```
public craeteLineChart(dataList: TransformDateValueModel[], root: HTMLDivElement): d3.Selection<SVGSVGElement, any, any, any> {
    // .....
    return canvas;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change html() to append()

```
tr.selectAll("div")
        .data(function (d, i) {
            return d;
        })
        .enter().append("div")
        .attr('class', function (d, i) {
            return "" + KpiMatrix.COLUMNS[i];
        })
        .append(function (d) {
            let div = document.createElement('div');
            if (Array.isArray(d)) {
                that.craeteLineChart(d, div);
            } else {
                div.innerHTML = d;
            }
            return div;
        });
```